# Помогите разобраться с моделями, правильно ли я делаю, может есть способ проще?

Tags: php, phalcon

Связываю модели так:

```
Units 
$this->belongsTo("units_id", "Structure", "id");

Ingredients 
$this->belongsTo("ingredients_id", "Structure", "id");

Structure
$this->hasMany("ingredients_id", "Ingredients", "id");
$this->hasMany("units_id", "Units", "id");

Recipes
$this->hasMany("id", "Structure", "recipes_id");
```

**Вот тут может быть как то можно проще сложить все данные**

Код которым составляю json массив:

```
 $recipes = Recipes::find();
    $paginator = new Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model(array(
        "data" => $recipes,
        "limit" => 5,
        "page" => $page
    ));
    $page = $paginator->getPaginate();

    foreach ($page->items as $rec) {
        $temp = array();
        foreach ($rec->Structure as $row) {
            foreach ($row->Ingredients as $key => $item) {
                $item->mer = $row->Units[$key]->name;
                $item->shortcut = $row->Units[$key]->shortcut;
                $item->count = $row->count;
                $temp[] = $item;
            }
        }
        $rec->ingredients = $temp;
    }
    echo json_encode($page);
```

Диограмма БД:

[image: Диограмма базы данных]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первый взгляд с нормализацией БД всё ок. Но вот с циклом проблемка, запросов к базе слишком много. Не знаю как в Falcon, но в любом уважающем себя фреймворке должен быть Eager Loading. Он формирует запрос вида

```
select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

То есть достаёт сразу все необходимые записи, вместо того чтобы доставать их по одной.
Думаю Фалькон тоже умеет данные доставать заранее, уделите внимание этому вопросу. :)